# Count or detect sprites passing from lines

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry

I have a simulation in which thousands of agents (multi-pixel sprites) move to different directions. There are imaginary (not drawn in the space) detection lines in the simulation space, specified by their coordinates.

What is an efficient method of detecting and counting the agents which pass each of the lines? (only the first time an agent passes the line will be counted).

Two simple methods come to my mind:

1- In each simulation step (after all agents have moved one pixel) draw the imaginary lines and see which agents the lines cut, increase the counter for the lines and mark the agent as passed through the specific lines.

2- For each "agent move", check whether it is on the line (how? draw the line each time?) , then again save the line as passed and increase the counter of the line.

[image]

Comment: which programming language are you using ?

Comment: I am more interested in an efficient algorithm. But I'll implement in C++.

Comment: Do agents move in random directions or single direction ? Are imaginary lines fixed at some coordinates ?

Comment: I think this could check if a point is on a line: `(x - x1) / (x2 - x1) == (y - y1) / (y2 - y1) && x >= x2 && x <= x1 && y >= y2 && y <= y1` but with thousands of them per second, it may not be fast enough, as you suggest.

Comment: @bjskishore123 : Agents move in any direction they want (but they are more likely to move perpendicular to those lines, but not always). yes, lines are fixed.

Comment: @groovy: I think your method will only work in specific situations. 1) in the case of horizontal and vertical lines we will have division by zero 2) You have assumed x1>x2 and y1>y2, which is not valid all the time 3) Even if assumption in 2 holds, the last 4 conditions may be true while the point is not on the line.

Comment: @wmac if the line is vertical or horizontal, then it seems even easier, you just check if y==y1 (horizontal) or x==x1 (vertical) and test the inequality for the other...but can you please give an example where all my statements evaluate to true and the point is still not on the line?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good approach with a lot of objects and a few lines will be the following:

First, after your object will move, you calculate an equation of a line against its center, if it's way off (the effective distance is moer than its radius), you check if the object was close to the line before (via a list attached to a line), if so, drop the reference from that list. If it's close enough, you perform a thorough test against that object's shape and the line, if they intersect, you record he object as "just intersected", and add its reference to the line's list of nearby objects.

If your objects are mathematical dots, and your lines are infinite, you give your objects a set of boolean values, each corresponding to a line, and true value indicatin g positive result of the equation, and false indicating negative, and check for each move if the sign just flipped. Each flip indicates a crossing of the line.

This method allows to correctly detect intersections, exclude unnecessary calculations if the objects' shapes are complex (for circles if the distance to line is less than the radius, then they intersect) and keeps track of the intersections that last for more than one iteration of movement.

Comment: Thanks Vesper. There are interesting ideas in your post. However, if we have 10,000 agents, according your method, I need to check the distance of every single agent with every single line. If I have 10 detection lines, that would be 100,000 checks. Unless we limit the checks to a subset of nearby agents (which is a complication again, since we need to check the distance to know who is near and who is far).

Comment: Anything else requires additional data about the movement of agents, maybe more. Say if the movement is erratic but will never exceed a given constant, also the size of an agent does not exceed a constant, you can split space by an orthogonal grid of size of the sum of both constants, so that each agent cannot cross more than one boundary within an interval, then for each line create a subset of grid that's worthy to check for distance to the line, and if an agent is outside of that grid subset, the distance check is not performed.

Comment: It is possible to define a rectangle proximity around the line (2 x,y pairs). We then do a more simple proximity check on the agent coordinates, if agent is in the proximity then we do the more complex calculation you suggested to see whether it is on the line or not.

Comment: You imply that the lines are finite, right? If so, there will be a false negative check if an agent is touching one of the endpoints of that line, while its center never crosses the rectangle that bounds the line.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

1. For every agent, find the straight distance to all the lines and store the shortest distance value.
2. Keep reducing distance by 1 every time agent moves.
3. When distance becomes zero, check whether any line coordinates are intersecting with Agent coordinates.
4. If yes, count it and mark it as counted. No further checks required on this agent. Go to step 2 to process other agents.
5. If no, go to step 1

In this algorithm, no need to compare the agent coordinates with line coordinates for every agent move. That way, it is efficient.

First step takes O(N) time for each agent, where N is the number of lines.

Comment: I should admit it is a wise plan even though it seems strange at first. And the complexity is very good.